# Background color of disabled Spinner

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to set the background color of the Spinner, if disabled.

Here is what I tried in my kv-file:

```
<MySpinner@Spinner>:
    background_normal: ''
    background_disabled_normal: ''
    disabled_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    background_disabled_color: (1,1,1,1)
    background_color: (0.62,0.67,0.72,1)
```

Obviously the  `background_disabled_color` is not the right parameter. But what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It inherits from `Button`, therefore if it's not in the `spinner.py` file, it'll be in [`button.py`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/button.py#L90)

You can see that `Button` uses images for the background and with `background_color` it's only tinted, yet there's no `background_disabled_color` (afaik). The background works like this - you set `background_color` and if the widget is disabled, it tints the default background image for disabled (which is little bit [darker](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png)):

```
Button:
    text: 'jump'
    disabled: True
    # background_disabled_normal: ''  # allow to see the behavior w/o default disabled bg
    background_color: (1,0,0,1)
```

To achieve another color for disabled widget than the default `background_color` you need to change the `background_color` when the `Button` is disabled (in your case `Spinner`):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    Spinner:
        id: special
        values: [str(i) for i in range(10)]
        size_hint_y: None
        text: 'jump'
        disabled: True
        #background_disabled_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,0,0,1) if not self.disabled else (0,1,0,1)
    Button:
        on_release: special.disabled = not special.disabled
''')
class Test(BoxLayout): pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Note that this won't work for the `DropDown`-like children, because those use [different](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/spinner.py#L48) class, so to change them you'll need to change properties of that class.